# Como poner disponible los datos del Usuario para todos los métodos de un controlador Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un controlador con siguiente codigo de Laravel, donde intento recuperar los datos del usuario para poder usarlos en todos los métodos de la clase:

```
public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware('auth');
$user = Auth::user();
$this->db_clientes = $user->db_clientes;
}
```

Al ejecutar me regresa:

Trying to get property 'db_clientes' of non-object

pero si  pongo las dos lineas

```
$user = Auth::user();
$this->db_clientes = $user->db_clientes;
```

dentro de un metodo diferente al constructor, funciona ok. Como que dentro del constructor parece no funcionar y no entiendo porque ya que el usuario se encuentra registrado.
 ¿**Como hago para que la info del usuario este presente en todos los métodos sin tener que agregar estas dos lineas en cada uno de ellos?**

Comment: No tengo una propiedad declarada, pero lo acabo de hacer ni bien declaro la clase y antes de iniciar el método constructor, y tampoco funciona. Aparte lo raro que si pongo las dos lineas de código dentro de cualquier método, funciona ok, pero si lo hago en el constructor, me da error.

Comment: Algo mas, si dentro del constructor invoco esta linea $user = Auth::user(); y hago vardump, me da NULL

Comment: ¿Porque podría ser que dentro del constructor, no levante los datos del usuario y traiga null ?

Comment: El tema estaria visto en este link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-in-controller-construct

Comment: Parece que la solucion esta aqui, aun no la pruebo: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors

Answer (score 1):

Si revisamos la guía de actualización de la versión de 5.3 de Laravel, la [documentación nos dice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors):

> #### Sesión en el constructor
>
> En versiones anteriores de Laravel, se podía acceder a las variables
>   de sesión o al usuario autenticado en el constructor de su
>   controlador. Esto nunca tuvo la intención de ser una característica
>   explícita del frameworks. En Laravel 5.3+, no se puede acceder a la
>   sesión o usuario autenticado desde el constructor del controlador
>   porque el middleware aún no se ha ejecutado.
>
> Como alternativa, puede definir un middleware de tipo Closure
>   directamente en el constructor de su controlador. Antes de usar esta
>   función, asegúrese de que su aplicación ejecute Laravel `5.3.4` o
>   superior:
>
> ```php
> class ProjectController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * All of the current user's projects.
>      */
>     protected $projects;
>
>     /**
>      * Create a new controller instance.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
>             $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;
>
>             return $next($request);
>         });
>     }
> ```

Entonces aplicando a tu caso, puedes hacerlo siguiente:

```php
protected $db_clientes;

//

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->db_clientes = Auth::user()->db_clientes;

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```